# Sorting files using glob

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I am trying to read a bunch of csv files using glob in python. I want to read all the files in ascending order and then assign the data from each file to a different array.

My code right now looks like this:

```py
for idx, f in enumerate (glob.glob(os.path.join(gen_path, "*.csv"))):
    data[idx] = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=False)
```

Can anyone help read the files in a sorted way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob` returns a list of strings.  Just sort it.

````
for idx, f in enumerate(sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(gen_path,"*.csv")))):
```
````

Comment: I have tried that but unfortunately that doesn't help. I can still see that the output files are not sorted according to the of csv files in the folder.

Comment: Then you've done something wrong.  Sorting can't not work.  Do you have numbers in your names?  Remember that 10, 100, and 1000 all sort before 2.  Perhaps you should post some of your file names in the question.

Comment: The problem was with the names e.g. i have data files names as "gen1-er1.csv", "gen2-er2.csv", "gen3-vp5.csv", and so on until gen258... 
After renaming these files, the problem was resolved. Thank you so much @Tim Roberts

Comment: As a side note, there IS a way to do sorting with filenames with embedded numbers.  You basically write a transform that changes the names into a list or tuple `('gen',1,'-er',1,'.csv')`, and sort with that key function.